# Invoking Firebase listener to run

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, event-listener

I'm trying to determine whether or not I download data in my android application. I can do this by making the method return true when it does download data, but the listener doesn't seem to be invoked until all other code is finished running (meaning it waits until a pause in your code). So I'm wondering if there is a way to sort of "forcibly" invoke these listeners? Perhaps by creating the listener in a different thread? Would this work or would it be a waste of time? I've already tried to sleep on the main thread for a few seconds, but that doesn't seem to do it either. If it wouldn't work, could you explain when exactly these listeners are invoked? Thanks in advance.

To add onto my question, I am NOT using the realtime database. I understand how realtime triggers work, but I am using the Firestore, so I am only getting data once, not getting realtime updates :)

Comment: Don't sleep on the main thread. That just blocks processing. Put your "all other code" (that seems to be blocking the listener call-back) onto another thread.

Comment: Okay thank you! I will try this out tomorrow and let you know how it works. I appreciate the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed with the API calls that deal with reading and writing data are fully `asynchronous`. This means that the call always returns immediately, without blocking the code to wait for a result. The results come some time later, whenever they’re ready, since it may take some time for this. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. So Firebase, already is using another thread (other than the main thread) to get the work done.

Calling a synchronous function on your app’s main thread could freeze the app indefinitely, which is a terrible UX. On Android, it could also soft-crash with an Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog.

Doug Stevenson, has explained in his [post](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) everything that you need to know about Fireabse asynchronous behaviour and what you need to do/avoid when dealing with Firebase.

Comment: That post was very helpful. It really helped me understand the full concept of the asynchronous calls. Thank you for linking that!